# "Несмотря на то(,) что". Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли ещё запятая:

**Несмотря на то что феномен был инвалидом, он был счастлив.**

Comment: Трудно представить себе контекст, в котором это предложение читалось бы хорошо. Если не называть человека по имени, то я написал бы "этот феномем", "наш феномен" и т.п.

Comment: М_Г, ты опять о смысле, а вопрос исключительно формальный, можно так же расположить любую белиберду.

Comment: @Galina Avanesova:  Ну, если формально, то предупреждать надо, а то у меня нервы слабые :)))

Answer (score 2):

"Ещё" - не нужна; запятая, одна, нужна именно там, где стоит у Вас: перед главным предложением.

Союз *несмотря на то(,) что* в начале предложения не расчленяется.

См. [ПУНКТУАЦИЯ В КОНСТРУКЦИЯХ С СОСТАВНЫМИ ПОДЧИНИТЕЛЬНЫМИ СОЮЗАМИ](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3)

> В) **Если придаточная часть предшествует главной – запятая ставится
> только после всего придаточного предложения**.
>
> *С тех пор как вечный судия // Мне дал всеведанье пророка, // В очах людей читаю я // Страницы злобы и порока.* М. Лермонтов, Пророк.
> *Вместо того чтобы становиться толпой против толпы, люди расходятся врозь, нападают поодиночке.* Л. Толстой, Война и мир. *В случае если
> Исполнитель не выполнил своих обязательств в сроки, указанные в
> настоящем Договоре, Заказчик вправе расторгнуть Договор.*